# Custom blog page on Wordpress (PHP) - Pagination

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, pagination

I'm trying to display first 5 posts with custom thumbnails and titles on [this page](http://fusion.fusionconstruction.co.uk/latest-news/)  and I need to display only the titles for the next 5 posts and then the pagination. You can see an example of what I need [by clicking here](http://www.cyclosport.org/). (see the posts on the left)

Below is the custom template I'm using on the page.

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">
<div id="content" role="main">

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts($args);
if( have_posts() ) :?>

<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' );?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post-thumb-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(632,305));?></a>
            <p class="thumb-title2"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            <p class="news-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></p>
            <div id="post-excerpt">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>
<article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
<header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h1>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-content">
<p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></p>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
<?php
// amount of posts shown with thumbnail
// post 6 .. pagesize (wp-admin > settings > reading) will be displayed as link only
$withThumb = 5; 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if ($withThumb-- > 0) { ?>
        <div class="post-thumb-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(632,305));?></a>
            <p class="thumb-title2"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            <p class="news-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></p>
            <div id="post-excerpt">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="post-title">
            <p class="thumb-title2">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This is breaking my page. No luck.

Comment: Could be, didn't test it, but got any error messages/warnings?

Comment: Nopes. Just an empty page. I'm sure I replaced my code correctly as I checked it twice.

Comment: Any help mate? :( I'm stuck in this loop

Comment: Tested it and code seems to be OK. To be sure: just replace the part between `<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' );?>` and `<?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>`. If this still doesn't work, could you check your servers error log and post the entries added to the log after a page refresh?

Comment: OK, I just did it. The page is loading fine but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Make sure to display more than 5 posts per page (`/wp-admin > Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most`) or decrease `$withThumb`.

Comment: Oh yes. It was set to 5 earlier. I changed it to 6 and that did the trick. Cheers for your help mate. :)